# gsutil cp succeeds but upload_from_filename() method from storage client fails

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I want to upload a file to GCS using the google storage client in python but its failing with a permissions issue, however `gsutil cp` succeeds. I can't understand why.

Here is what I have run using `gsutil`:

```sh
BUCKET=abc
$ gcloud iam service-accounts keys create --iam-account $ACCOUNT key_file.json
created key [5006838b5984f1d3b4de6523239e9bbd2c7f7047] of type [json] as [key_file.json] for [serviceaccountname@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file key_file.json
Activated service account credentials for: [serviceaccountname@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
$ touch test.txt
$ gsutil cp test.txt gs://${BUCKET}/test.txt     
Copying file://test.txt [Content-Type=text/plain]...
/ [1 files][    0.0 B/    0.0 B]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects.
```

Here is what I have attempted from python:

```py
from google.cloud import storage
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'key_file.json' #same file as downloaded above
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = "abc" #the bucket name
source_file_name = "test.txt"
destination_blob_name = f"{source_file_name}"
with open(source_file_name, 'w') as f:
        f.write("lorem ipsum")
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
```

That `upload_from_filename()` function fails with error:

> google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/abc/o?uploadType=multipart: ('Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>)

I'm baffled. I would have thought that if this worked from gsutil it would work using the python storage client. Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: Will this python script run outside Google Cloud at the end (on prem, on other cloud)?

Comment: It was run outside Google cloud. It was run in my laptop.

Comment: Yes, but at the end? It will also run on your laptop? Where do you plan to deploy this script?

Comment: ah I see. This script is intended to run as a test in a CI pipeline. The test will run to verify that `$ACCOUNT` has appropriate permissions to carry out the things it needs to be able to carry out.

Comment: Are the key file and the script file are in the same folder? if so, did you try to set the full file path? *Note: my first questions were to avoid the service account key file creation, because it's a possible security issue*

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responses. I've solved the problem. Please see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gotten to the bottom of this problem. It was twofold.

1. I discovered that the code would succeed if the storage object `destination_blob_name` did *not* already exist. If the object *did* exist then the error explained above would occur.
2. Permission for `$ACCOUNT` to access the bucket was provided by a custom role that was applied to the bucket. When I added permission `storage.objects.get` & `storage.objects.delete` to that custom role then my code succeeded, even if the object already existed.

I've discovered that `storage.objects.get` & `storage.objects.delete` are described as

> - Read object data and metadata, excluding ACLs
> - Delete objects

*https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions#object_permissions*

The learning I've taken away from this is that under certain circumstances (e.g. when the destination object already exists) then [`gsutil cp`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) requires different permissions to [`google.cloud.storage.blob.upload_from_filename()`](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/_modules/google/cloud/storage/blob.html#Blob.upload_from_filename). If anyone out there can elucidate the difference between those two operations then I'd love to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

This error (403) indicates that the user was not authorized by Google Cloud Storage to make the request, basically you need to keep in mind that:

- A common cause of this error is that the bucket permissions (bucket
  ACL) are not set properly to allow your app access. See [Google Cloud
  Storage Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication) for information on setting up access.
- You can see the different causes on the official [Cloud Storage
  Documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-status#403%E2%80%94forbidden)